# Regexp to find all CSS rules not ending with ";"

Tags: css, regex

I'm trying to write regexp to find all rules in CSS filest that don't have semicolon at the end:

```css
.abc {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center /* <-- like this one */
    width: 100%;
}
```

i've tried this `[^;\{\}]\n` but it not excluding `{` and `}` from search. Any ideas?

Comment: In what language? CSS won't do this by itself.

Comment: I'm trying to find regular expresion for doing this, and then use it to search in multiple files at once.

Comment: @Bodzio In which programming language? PHP? or within an editor?

Comment: Do you have a bunch of files you want to check?

Comment: In NetBeans, Amal Murali answer is doing the trick so thank you guys :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### What you need is a CSS parser.

However, if this is a one-off job, and your regex engine supports [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use this regex:

```
^.*(?<![;{}])$
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Debuggex.com]

`(?<![;{}])` is a negative lookbehind that asserts that the line should end with a character that's not `;`, `{` or `}`.

Note that the regex is far from perfect and fails to match properly if a CSS block is used by more than one class/id or if every class/id is separated by a line break.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yQ3gY5/1)

Comment: Why the downvotes? An explanation might help me realize what's wrong and possibly improve the answer.

Comment: This regex fails if a css block is used by more than 1 class/id and every class/id is separated by a line break. (I didn't downvote you though)

Comment: You are not ensuring being within curly brackets

Comment: @revo: I'm not. As I said, this regex is far from perfect. The OP should use a CSS parser if they want to handle all cases perfectly. From the OP's comment under the question, it seems they were trying to use the regex in an editor ("*In NetBeans, Amal Murali answer is doing the trick so thank you guys :)*"). :)

Comment: It's better to add a lookahead statement. It works on valid CSS. It's optimized for multiple IDs and classes which checks for brackets. `(?=[^{]*}).*(?<![;}{}])$` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iZ1vX1/1)

Answer (score -1):

In perl you can easily do this,
e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# open your file
open(FILE,"filename.css");
my @fileLines = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my $lineCount=1;
# check all lines of your file
foreach my $line(@fileLines){
    # erase endline spaces
    $line=~ s/\s+$//;
    # erase begin of line
    $line=~ s/^\s+//;
    # simple perl regex, it doesn't watch for comments
    if($line !~ /\;$/ && $line !~ /{$/ && $line !~/}$/){
        print $lineCount.':'.$line.'\n';
    }
$lineCount++;
}
```

This small program will show you lines which not finnish by ';'.

Answer (score -2):

You could just run the file through http://csslint.net

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting this?

Comment: Thanks, I know this tool, but this time I need just this regexp (I need to search only for this semicolon error in multiple files)